# How do I stop friends from getting notifications about what I do on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Friends and family (who are not in my Close Friends group) are getting notifications when I post or like something on Facebook. How do I stop this?

Comment: The suggested duplicate question is solely about "close friends", this question appears to be about (ordinary) friends. These are different.

Comment: As above, it was also suggested by a flagger that this situation was in fact different than the duplicate.  I clarified the point and reopened.

Comment: Uh...that's how Facebook works. Your friends are connected to you because they're interested in things you say and do. If you don't want them to know, either don't post it on Facebook or don't be friends with them on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

When you post, click on More Options, then Custom to only show it to a select list of people.

To hide your likes from certain people, do the following.  On your timeline, click on Likes, then Edit, then a Category blue triangle and then Custom.